# Raw data has column labels spread across two rows

Tags: r, format, tidyverse

I have a problem with the humans here; they're giving me Citizen Science data in spreadsheets formatted to be attractive and legible.  I figured out the right sequence of `pivot`s `_longer` and `_wider` to get it into an analyzable format but first I had to do a whole bunch of hand edits to make the column labels usable.  I've just been given a corrected spreadsheet so now I have to do the same hand edits all over.  Can I avoid this?

```
reprex <- read_csv("reprex.csv", col_names = FALSE)
```

gives:

```
  X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10  
1 NA    NA    2014  NA    NA    2015  NA    NA    2016  NA   
2 NA    Total F     M     Total F     M     Total F     M    
3 SiteA 180   92    88    134   40    94    34    20    14   
4 SiteB NA    NA    NA    247   143   104   8     8     0    
5 SiteC 237   194   43    220   95    125   62    45    17
```

I want column labels like "2014 Total", "2014 F", ... like so:

```
  Location `2014 Total` `2014 F` `2014 M` `2015 Total` `2015 F` `2015 M` `2016 Total` `2016 F` `2016 M`
1 SiteA             180       92       88          134       40       94           34       20       14
2 SiteB              NA       NA       NA          247      143      104            8        8        0
3 SiteC             237      194       43          220       95      125           62       45       17
```

...which would allow me to twist it up until I get to something like:

```
  Location date  Total     F     M
1 SiteA    2014    180    92    88
2 SiteB    2014     NA    NA    NA
3 SiteC    2014    237   194    43
4 SiteA    2015    134    40    94
5 SiteB    2015    247   143   104
6 SiteC    2015    220    95   125
7 SiteA    2016     34    20    14
8 SiteB    2016      8     8     0
9 SiteC    2016     62    45    17
```

The part from the second table to the third I've got; the problem is in how to get from the first table to the second.  It would seem like you could pivot the first and then fill in the missing `date`s with `fill(.direction="updown")` except that the dates are the grouping value you need to be following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this example we could do like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_helper <- df %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols= everything()) %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = "up") %>% 
  mutate(x = lead(value, 11)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  unite("name", c(value, x), sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name) 
         

df %>% 
  setNames(names(df_helper)) %>% 
  rename(Location = x) %>% 
  slice(-c(1:2))
```

```
 Location 2014 Total 2014 F 2014 M 2015 Total 2015 F 2015 M 2016 Total 2016 F 2016 M
3    SiteA        180     92     88        134     40     94         34     20     14
4    SiteB       <NA>   <NA>   <NA>        247    143    104          8      8      0
5    SiteC        237    194     43        220     95    125         62     45     17
```

Comment: Ah -- I get it; thank you!  I think I have a block that keeps me from thinking of breaking off pieces of the whole -- seems too invasive or something.  But obviously!